# Fetch title and description from a YouTube video URL in Andorid

Tags: android, youtube-data-api

I want to build an android app that can fetch **title** and **description** from a youtube video Url and show it in text view.

Comment: well, this is not the best approach but you can scrap the the youtube video page and get the title and description from the page there are so many sdks used in youtube like that of twitter and facebook and even the html meta tags

Comment: ok, you told us what you want. Now tell us what stops you from doing that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the URL given below to get the details:

> https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?id=YOURVIDEOID&key=YourAPIKEY&part=snippet&fields=items(snippet/title,snippet/description)

Here,

- id is the Youtube video id
- key is your youtube api key
- part is the kind of details you are intrested in
- fields is the fields in the parts you are intrested in

part and fields are used to limit the response

You shall refer to https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/getting-started#part for API details

You shall hit the URL and parse the fetched JSON to suit your needs

Comment: @Hamza Ramzan Happy to know that it worked for you! Please do consider marking the same as accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [jsoup](https://jsoup.org/) for this.

> jsoup is a Java library for working with real-world HTML. It provides
>   a very convenient API for extracting and manipulating data, using the
>   best of DOM, CSS, and jquery-like methods.

You can fetch the HTML from the  YouTube using the video URL and then find its data.